# Telethon Websocket - Parse Predicatable Yet Complicated Text

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Typical response I get in EtherDrops is the following.  Some info changed to protect wallets.

I am trying to move all pieces to json for future use.  I cannot think of a simple method to do this without a huge amount of looped parsing.  Im just kinda stuck on best way to break this apart.  The Send and Receive can occasionaly be inverted.  So the message order could be "Sent" as the 2nd line or it may end up being in the 3rd line and "Received" ends up on 2nd line.  Hence the complication.  Thank you.

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
with TelegramClient('name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    # client.send_message('me', 'Hello, myself!')
    print(client.download_profile_photo('me'))


    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=['EtherDROPS6_bot']))  # pattern='(?i).*Hello'
    async def handler(event):
        # print(event.text)
        wallet = event.text
        if "Sent" in wallet and "Received" in wallet:
            print('^^^^^ START OF EVENT ^^^^^ ')
            print(type(wallet))  #<<<< <class 'str'>
            print(wallet)
            # res = wallet.replace(']', '\n').replace(')', '\n').replace('[', '').replace('(', '')
            print('^^^^^ END OF EVENT ^^^^^ ')
```

The entire message is a single string.

```
[WALLET_1](https://etherscan.io/address/0xABC) ETH
Sent: 0.1 ETH (~$304) To: [Uniswap V3: Router 2
](https://etherscan.io/address/0xUNISWAP_CONTRACT)Received: 4,780 [ERC-20_TOKEN_NAME](https://etherscan.io/token/0xTOKEN_CONTRACT) From: [0xfa17..ABCD
](https://etherscan.io/address/0xCONTRACT_PAIR)[Tx hash](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xTXHASH)
```

I want it to look something like this in the end.   Open to options on end result.

```
data = {
    "TRADE":
        {
            "WALLET": [
                {
                    "OWNER": ""
                }
            ],
            "RECEIVED": [
                {
                    "RCVD TOKEN": "",
                    "RCVD TOKEN QTY": "",
                    "RCVD TOKEN CONTRACT ADDRESS": ""
                }
            ],
            "SENT": [
                {
                    "SENT TOKEN": "",
                    "SENT TOKEN QTY": "",
                    "SENT TOKEN CONTRACT ADDRESS": ""
                }
            ],
            "VALUATION": [
                {
                    "SENT VALUE": ""
                }
            ],
            "NETWORK": [
                {
                    "NETWORK": ""
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `if "Sent" and "Received" in wallet:` does what you think. This can be rewritten as `if True and "Received" in wallet:`.

Comment: You make a good point.  I checked that and fixed it by using the following. 

            if "Sent" in wallet and "Received" in wallet:

Comment: Does that also fix the original problem?